# How can I make my table longer so the max width is the width of the text

Tags: tables, overleaf

I have a table that is too large for my page. I have adjusted it so it is page wide but now it is not readable as the letters have gotten too small. Is there a way to make my table longer so it is both readable and not too wide for the page? This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\textbf{Authors}        & \textbf{Material}  & \textbf{Method}                                 & \textbf{Conditions}                                                                                                                                       & \textbf{Important contact angles (°)}                                                                                                                                              & \textbf{Other significant findings}                                                                                                                                                                                     \\
Al-Yaseri and Jha, 2021 & Basalt             & Empirical correlations of contact angles of CO2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pressure: 5 - 20 MPa\\ \\ Temperature: 323 K\\ \\ Salinity: synthetic brine3\end{tabular}                                      & \textless{}20 (at reservoir conditions)                                                                                                                                            & Contact angle increases with pressure                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
Zeng et al., 2022       & Calcite            & Modeled                                         &                                                                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                                                                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Temperature increase decreases contact angle\\ \\ Increasing salinity or stearic acid concentration increases contact angle\end{tabular}                                                     \\
Hou et al., 2022        & Carbonate rocks    & Tilted plate goniometric                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pressure: 0.1 - 30 MPa\\ \\ Temperature: 25, 40, 55, 70 °C\\ \\ Salinity: 3 wt\% NaCl\end{tabular}                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}45.5 - 88.4 over pressure range\\ \\ 45.5 - 20.0 over temperature range\end{tabular}                                                                    & Contact angle increased with pressure , decreased with temperature and increased with salinity                                                                                                                          \\
Esfandyari et al., 2022 & Calcite and Basalt & Captive bubble                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pressure: 1 - 10 MPa\\ \\ Temperature:\\ 20-80 °C\\ \\ Salinity: distilled water and brine(2)\end{tabular}                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Calcite: 35 - 93 (over entire range of conditions)\\ \\ Basalt: 17 -35 degree (over entire range of conditions)\end{tabular}                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lower temperature decreased influence of pressure on contact angle\\ \\ Contact angles increase with temperature and pressure for both rocks\end{tabular}                                    \\
Hosseini et al., 2022a  & Basalt             & tilted plate                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Pressure: 5 - 20 MPa\\ \\ Temperature: 308, 343 K\\ \\ Salinity: 1.05 M brine (0.864 mol NaCl \& 0.136 mol\\ KCl)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}30 - 62 (over the entire range of conditions)\\ \\ Equilibrium contact angle increased to almost 90 degrees for rock aged in stearic acid.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Wettability increased with all varying parameters\\ \\ High contact angles with increasing stearic acid concentration\\ \\ System became weakly water wet at higher temperature\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

}
```

Comment: The esiest solution is to use tabularx and replace most if not all of your l columns with X columns.

Comment: never scale tables with \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{``, `\resizebox` etc, the results are not usable, as you see,

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options